# Compiling SFML on linux (ubuntu)

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, terminal, sfml

In compiling a SFML app,

- I need to first create the cpp file with the SFML code and save file
- Then write the command: `g++ -c main.cpp` to compile and create the object file.
- Finally, to create SFML app, i need to write the command:
  `g++ main.o -o sfml-app -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system`

I was successfully able to compile and run my first app, but can't we shorten this process, I mean do I have to type out this every time I compile, and make application?

I have this question also about compiling c++ files in general. Every time I have to write `g++ filename.cpp -o filename`. How can I shorten this process?
Thank you.

Comment: see build automation tool like make, cmake...

Comment: @Garf365: say a few more words and post it as an answer

Comment: @Ionut it's done, if you have a feedback to give, don't hesitate ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is very common to use a `Makefile` on `Linux`. The `Makefile` is simpler if you name your main *source file* the same as you want your finished program to be called.

So if you rename your `main.cpp` file to `sfml-app.cpp` and then create a file called `Makefile` and copy this text into it:

```
# optional flags (if the compiler supports it)
CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11

# HIGHLY RECOMMENDED flags
CXXFLAGS += -Wall -Wextra -pedantic-errors

# required for SFML programs
LDLIBS := $(shell pkg-config sfml-all --libs)

# The rest will turn any source file ending in .cpp
# into a program of the same name

SOURCES := $(wildcard *.cpp)
PROGRAMS := $(patsubst %.cpp,%,$(SOURCES))

all: $(PROGRAMS)

clean:
    $(RM) $(PROGRAMS)
```

Type: `make` to build the programs and `make clean` to remove them.

**Note:** The indentation of the `$(RM) $(PROGRAMS)` command **must** be a `TAB`, not spaces.

If you want to compile another program in the same directory simply create another source file in the directory `another-app.cpp` and `make` will automatically turn it into a program.

This `Makefile` will turn any source file (ending in .cpp) into a program of the same name.

**Note:** When you want to build larger, multi-file programs you will need a different `Makefile`. If you are serious about programming then you *should* learn `make`.

**Here you can [learn all about make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/).**

Comment: Thank you! I have a problem, when typing `make main.cpp` in terminal, I get error `Makefile:19: *** missing separator.  Stop.`

Comment: Thanks i fixed it! It was due to using spaces and not tabs! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

You can write a .sh script that executes the commands:

```
g++ -c main.cpp
g++ main.o -o sfml-app -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system
```

Comment: Simple solution, which works fine with one file project. But when you have more files, which dependency, it become quickly hard to maintain, and too long to build app.

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to use build automation tool. A lot of differents tools exists, each with strong and weak points.

Personnaly, for small project, I use Make. You write in a file, named Makefile, rules which descibe relation between files and how to realize each step. For example, the *minimal* Makefile for your project will be :

```
sfml-app: main.o
    g++ main.o -o sfml-app -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system

main.o: main.c
    g++ -c main.cpp
```

This file is located at root of project. You just have to enter "make" command to launch build. If you want, you will find a lot of documentation on internet.  see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Make_%28software%29 I encourage you to read about makefile to use it correctly and to be able to use its power.

Also, someone can advise you to use another build automation tool: it's a personnaly choice! You will find a list of existing tool here (not exhaustive): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_build_automation_software

Comment: Bad `Makefile` ; should use the standard variables (`COMPILE.cc`, `CXXFLAGS`); see default rules given with `make -p`. And you *always* should invoke `g++` with `-Wall -Wextra` and probably also `-g`

Comment: **Bad** is too harsh, it's a minimal working Makefile that solves the problem. In this situation I think it's more appropriate for someone who hasn't heard of Make before because it's easier to understand than a *good* Makefile. If the OP wants to, he can read the docs and learn how to write good Makefiles, but he may be more inclined to do so if he can grasp the basics without first having to read the full Make manual.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I agree with you, we should use standard variables, I also agree with c++ flags. I use this. But it's not the question here. Also, I just give a preview of a build automation tool among many others. It's for this I encourage to read on internet some documentation!

Comment: @Ionut thanks you, it's really my objective with this answer!

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I add sentence to encourage everyone interested in makefile to read documentation. This answer _isn't_ a introduction to make and Makefile

Comment: If you want to compile just main.o for example, just use `make main.o`. I encourage really you to read about makefile. You will find a lot of helpfull information to well manage makefile. After reading, you can produce good makefile, using variable and other great stuff. You also can have a "template" makefile and use it for every of your project. Also, it's good to use some tricks like `%.o: %.cpp` which automate adding files. See Galik answer as example of more complete makefile

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a bash script I like to use on Linux. It has four modes, compile, compile and run, compile for release with optimization, and compile for release with optimization and then run the game.

Save this as build.sh, then using Linux terminal type "chmod +x build.sh"

```
#######!/bin/bash

appRunning=1

while [ $appRunning == 1 ]; do
    echo Compile debug[1], Compile and run debug[2], Compile release[3], Compile and run release[4], Exit[5]
    read user

    if [[ $user == 1 ]]; then
        clear
        echo Compiling for debug...
        echo
        g++ -c src/*.cpp -std=c++14 -Werror -m64
        g++ *.o -o bin/debug/Game -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system -lsfml-audio -lsfml-network
        read -n 1 -s
        clear

    elif [[ $user == 2 ]]; then
        clear
        echo Compiling and running for debug...
        echo
        g++ -c src/*.cpp -std=c++14 -Werror -m64
        g++ *.o -o bin/debug/Game -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system -lsfml-audio -lsfml-network
        ./bin/debug/Game
        read -n 1 -s
        clear

    elif [[ $user == 3 ]]; then
        clear
        echo Compiling for release...
        echo
        g++ -c src/*.cpp -std=c++14 -m64 -O3 -fexpensive-optimizations -s
        g++ *.o -o bin/release/Game -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system -lsfml-audio -lsfml-network
        read -n 1 -s
        clear

    elif [[ $user == 4 ]]; then
        clear
        echo Compiling and running for release...
        echo
        g++ -c src/*.cpp -std=c++14 -m64 -O3 -fexpensive-optimizations -s
        g++ *.o -o bin/release/Game -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system -lsfml-audio -lsfml-network
        ./bin/release/Game
        read -n 1 -s
        clear
    elif [[ $user == 5 ]]; then
        exit
    fi
done
```

It compiles all .cpp files located in a folder called "src" and outputs to bin/Game. Of course you can modify this to your own likings.